# Problema com menu + botões + lcd

Tags: c, pic

Olá.

Estou tendo dificuldades para fazer um programa em linguagem C com botões, lcd (16x2) e um PIC18F4550.

Abaixo, coloquei a descrição do programa e o código que eu tenho até agora, um filtro teclado e algumas configurações básicas do pic.

Eu estava tentando usar vários vetores para exibir as duas opções iniciais e depois funções para cada linha, mas estava ficando muito grande e confuso. E além de tudo, quando eu apertava outras sequências de botões o programa entendia como outra coisa e ia para outra tela que não era o que eu queria.

Então eu pensei nesse filtro teclado, mas falta implementar ele com as opções do lcd e tudo mais.

É mesmo necessário usar vários vetores? Eu preciso usar um vetor de caracter ou o que?

### Descrição do programa:

O programa começa com um simples menu com duas opções:

- Opção (a) e,
- opção (b)

Se eu apertar o botão "OK", a opção (a) será selecionada e então irá abrir uma tela com uma frase de duas linhas.

Para selecionar a opção (b) é necessário usar o botão "descer" e depois "OK". Então será aberto um menu com onze opções. Cada opção ocupará duas linhas do LCD (o LCD é 16x2).

Então, por exemplo, para selecionar a opção dois (2) é necessário apertar o botão "descer" e depois "OK".

Cada uma dessas onze opções, quando selecionadas, vão abrir informações de cerca de cinco linhas (um texto de cinco linhas, mais ou menos).

E quando, por exemplo, o usuário quiser voltar opções no menu de seleções das onze opções é só apertar o botão "voltar".

E se ele precisar ler as opções ou informações que ele já passou com o botão "descer", é só apertar "subir".

- (OK)     - RB0;
- (Voltar) - RB1;
- (Subir)  - RB2;
- (Descer) - RB3.

Código:

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lcd.h"
#ifndef _XTAL_FREQ
#define _XTAL_FREQ 16000000
#endif

//filtro teclado
#define MAX_FILTER_CNT     250

unsigned char Tecla1Cnt = 0;
unsigned char Tecla2Cnt = 0;
unsigned char Tecla3Cnt = 0;
unsigned char Tecla4Cnt = 0;

unsigned char Tecla1 = 0;
unsigned char Tecla2 = 0;
unsigned char Tecla3 = 0;
unsigned char Tecla4 = 0;

if (Tecla1 != RB0)
{
    Tecla1Cnt++;

    if (Tecla1Cnt > MAX_FILTER_CNT)
    {
        Tecla1Cnt  = 0;
        Tecla1  = RB0;
    } 
}
else
{
    Tecla1Cnt  = 0;
}

if (Tecla2 != RB1)
{
    Tecla2Cnt++;

    if (Tecla2Cnt > MAX_FILTER_CNT )
    {
        Tecla2Cnt  = 0;
        Tecla2  = RB1;
    } 
}
else
{
    Tecla2Cnt  = 0;
}

if (Tecla3 != RB2)
{
    Tecla3Cnt++;

    if (Tecla3Cnt > MAX_FILTER_CNT )
    {
        Tecla3Cnt  = 0;
        Tecla3  = RB2;
    } 
}
else
{
    Tecla3Cnt  = 0;
}

if (Tecla4  != RB3)
{
    Tecla4Cnt++;

    if(Tecla4Cnt > MAX_FILTER_CNT )
    {
        Tecla4Cnt  = 0;
        Tecla4  = RB3;
    } 
}
else
{
    Tecla4Cnt  = 0;
}

int main(void){

    TRISD = 0x00;
    TRISB = 0x0F;
    ADCON1 = 0XFF;
    CMCON = 0X07;
    T1CON = 0b11111001;
    PORTD = 0;
    for(aux = 0; aux < 100; aux++) 
        __delay_ms(10);
    lcd_init();

    while(1)
    {
        //manipulação dos botões e opções
    }
```

Comment: Difícil responder pois sua pergunta está confusa e o código também.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, companheiro. O microcontrolador `PIC` é maravilhoso para se trabalhar, mas é preciso conhecer um pouco a linguagem C e algumas características especificas do compilar que você escolher. Eu gosto particularmente do compilador `PCW` da `CCS`, e observei que você está usando o `MIKRO C`, certo? Eu conheço pouco deste compilador e suas sintaxes e características, mas fiz um código rapidamente que é bem genérico e que pode te ajudar bastante com os menus e as funções.
tomei a liberdade de tirar o botão voltar, pois achei meio inútil e no lugar ele fica como na opção 'a'. Claro que se você quiser, pode implementar o código com o uso dele.

Ainda não tive tempo para testar com um `PIC`, mas creio que vai funcionar. Logo mais eu edito (se possível editar a resposta, sou novo aqui) e coloco o resultado com o `PIC` e `LCD`.
Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <bibliotecas_gerais.h>

//definição dos pinos
#define subir    pino_desejado
#define descer   pino_desejado
#define ok       pino_desejado

int opcoes[][] ={{0,1},
                 {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}
                 };
int main(){
    /*
        configurações gerais e declarações gerais do microcontrolador...
    */
    printf("/fA. menu ");
    printf("B. menu ");
    if(opmenu1()==0){
        menu_tela_a();
    }else if(opmenu1()==1){
        opmenuB();
    }
}

int opmenu1(){
    int menu1=0
    int okk=0;
    do{
        if(menu1>1){
            menu1=1;
        }else if(menu1<0){
            menu1=0;
        }
       if(subir) {
          menu1--;
       }else if(descer){
          menu1++;
       }else if(ok){
           okk=1
       }
    }while(okk!=1);
    return menu1;
}

int opmenuB(){
    int menu2=0;
    int okk=0;
    do{
        if(menu2>11){
            menu2=11;
        }else if(menu2<0){
            menu2=0;
        }
       if(subir) {
          menu2--;
       }else if(descer){
          menu2++;
       }else if(ok){
           okk=1
       }
       menu_tela_b(okk,menu2);
    }while(okk!=1);
    return menu2;
}

void menu_tela_b(int operacao, int opc){
    do{
        switch (opcoes[menu1][opc]){
            case 0:
            case 1:
                printf("/f0. opcao ");
                printf("1. opcao ");
                break;
            case 2:
            case 3:
                printf("/f2. opcao ");
                printf("3. opcao ");
                break;
            case 4:
            case 5:
                printf("/f4. opcao ");
                printf("5. opcao ");
                break;
            case 6:
            case 7:
                printf("/f6. opcao ");
                printf("7. opcao ");
                break;
            case 8:
            case 9:
                printf("/f8. opcao ");
                printf("9. opcao ");
                break;
            case 10:
            case 11:
                printf("/f10. opcao ");
                printf("11. opcao ");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }while(operacao!=1);
}

void menu_tela_a()}{
    do{
        printf("frase....");
        printf("continuacao");
    }while(opmenu1()!=1);
}
```

Qualquer duvida, estou a disposição.